# Remove user level security from Access 97 mdb file

Tags: security, ms-access

I have an access file which is using user level security, I do not have the mdw or know the login details. I need to extract all the data, I cannot see the tables only yhe forms when I open this document. How can I extract all the data in all tables.

Comment: i have managed to get access 97 and export all tables into excel and import into 2010

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a lot of choices as far as I know:

- you can reconstruct the `.mdw` file by creating a new database and using the exact same username and PID of the original user, then use the new `.mdw` with the old database.
  You can use some of [the tools from Serge Gavrilov](http://accesstools.narod.ru/) to help you find the username and PID from a database.
- Have a look at the forums  on [UtterAccess.com](http://www.utteraccess.com/). There seem to be a lot of discussions regarding *lost mdw*.
- you can use some data repair services like at [EverythingAccess](http://www.everythingaccess.com/accessdatabaserepair.htm). Cost some money, but I'm sure they can recover your data.