# MS Access Permissions (MS Office 2010)

Tags: ms-access

I have started getting this error on MS Access when trying to click on a button, this was working fine until recently and no changes have been made that I am aware of.

"You don't have permissions to run 'Return to Main Menu From in Progress Form'

To run this object, you must have Open/Run permission for it.  For more information on permissions and who ca  set them, click Help."

Can anyone offer any assistance, how do I get permissions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-or-change-Access-2003-user-level-security-in-Access-2007-or-higher-0c6a10e7-966f-44f4-864e-5d2ef79439fa) to get some information on Access user-level security.

The error is a user-level security one, so I can assume you're using an `mdb` file with user-level security enabled. This error occurs when trying to open a form you don't have the open/run permission on.

You will need access to an account with the administrator privilege to change rights, or there are some more hacky ways to remove security but I'm not going to discuss them here.

If your file is actually an .accdb file, then some error must have occured, and I suggest decompiling the database.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately the guy who set the database up no longer works for the company, we are trying to find others who may has "administer" privilege level.  But what are these other "more hacky" ways or can you give a link?

Comment: Well... since I can just refer you to another question I guess it isn't against SO policy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807468/remove-user-level-security-from-access-97-mdb-file).